# Non-exhaustive Error in Basic Haskell Function

Tags: haskell, boolean, non-exhaustive-patterns

I'm new to Haskell and trying to put together a simple function to check whether or not two numbers are equal. This compiles, but when I try out a test of the program, it says that this is non-exhaustive. I don't understand how it can be non-exhaustive with a boolean function? Thanks in advance:

```
data Value = ConstInt Int
           | Numequal Value Value
           | Ctrue Bool
           | Cfalse Bool
            deriving (Read, Show)
eval:: Value -> Bool

eval (Numequal e1 e2) =
   let x = eval e1
       y = eval e2
         in case (x, y) of
            (i1, i2)  -> 
                if x == y
                then False
                else True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't finished your `eval` function. For example, suppose I call `eval (ConstInt 34)`. What should it return?

Also, think about what's in the body of your function. `eval` returns a Boolean, so both `x` and `y` will be Booleans and you're testing to see if they're equal. Is that what you want?

Comment: Well, since you didn't include many comments, I'm having a hard time understanding what you really want. That's why I'm asking - say in your own words what you want `eval` to really do, separate from the implementation of it.

Comment: Oh, okay. I just want eval to take two integers, and see if they're equal. If they are, then true. If they're not, then false. It seems so simple, but I don't understand how x and y are booleans here?

Comment: Ok, step back a moment. If that's what you really want, `eval` would look like this:  `eval x y = x == y` and you wouldn't need the `Value` datatype. But again, I get the feeling that's not what you really want.

Comment: In the eval that you described, how would you return a true or false value based on a test of 2 numbers? In order to better learn Haskell I have been working to develop an integer calculator, and wanted to include this function in there as well, to work on putting together different types of functions. For example, if I used a test of t1 = Numequal (ConstInt 1)(ConstInt 1), and then t2 = eval t1?

Comment: Okay, I think I may have figured out where I went wrong. (Quite a few places!) I took out the eval on x and y, so that it would just provide me with #s, and replaced the Value datatype. Oh...and I switched the True/False, so that they actually make sense!:)

Comment: I thought my name would be unique if I just stuck around Haskell questions. Guess I was wrong. ;)

Answer (score 4):

When using pattern matching, you have to handle *all* possible cases.

```
eval (Numequal e1 e2) = ...
eval _ = False -- or patterns for ConstInt, Ctrue and Cfalse
```

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you...When considering what could be entered I was, for some reason, only thinking in my head true/false.

Comment: Well, that's actually not true in Haskell. It's just that if you don't, runtime errors might result if you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your data type should be be `deriving (Eq)` for you to be able to make comparisons on it.

Comment: I tried this, but it is still coming up with a non-exhaustive pattern error in my test case.

Comment: Pattern matching can be used on any data type, not just instances of `Eq`.

Comment: @pelotom I was actually referring to the comparison `x == y`, not strictly to the pattern matching. Should have pointed it as '''a side note'''

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the `x == y`